# Origen de la palabra "lechosa"

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, venezuela

En Venezuela y no sé en qué otros países más, se usa la palabra *lechosa* para referirse a la papaya,. Me parece curioso que en ningún otro país se use el término.

¿Alguien sabe el origen de esta palabra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lechoza" no aparece en el diccionario de americanismos, aunque "Lechosa" sí:

> [**lechosa**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=lechosa.).
>
> I. 1.  Ho, ES:E, RD, PR, Ve. **papaya**, fruto.

También vemos en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lechosa) que "lechosa" puede referirse al nombre común de la papaya, y en la propia entrada:

> *Carica papaya* es una especie de planta arbustiva del género Carica en la familia Caricaceae. Su fruto se conoce comúnmente como papaya, papayón, olocotón, papayo, **lechosa o lechoza en República Dominicana y Venezuela**, frutabomba en Cuba, melón papaya, melón de árbol; y mamón en Argentina (también papaya más al sur del NE de su territorio) y Paraguay.
>
> [...]
>
> La savia [del tronco de la verdura] es de consistencia lechosa (de aquí su nombre de «lechosa»)
>
> [...]
>
> **Alergias y efectos colaterales**
>
> La papaya libera líquido de látex cuando no está maduro, lo que puede causar irritación y reacciones alérgicas, en algunas personas. **Por su color blanquecino se le denomina lechosa en países como Venezuela y República Dominicana**.
>
> Fuente: wikipedia para [Carica papaya](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carica_papaya)

Es posible que los países que no cultivan papaya (la mayoría de [productores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carica_papaya#Producci%C3%B3n) son países iberoamericanos) no estén familiarizados con este aspecto lechoso de la savia del tronco de la planta del árbol.

Las entradas de wikipedia y el diccionario de americanos llevan a pensar que "lechosa" se usa en Honduras, República Dominicana, Puerto Rico y Venezuela y "lechoza" posiblemente solo en República Dominicana y Venezuela.

Comment: Editare mi pregunta, ha sido un error ortografico, me refieria a lechosa

Comment: Parece ser que "lechoza" se usa, aunque de momento no lo recoja el diccionario (quizá es habla coloquial o no culta, pero viendo esa entrada de wikipedia, tu pregunta no está equivocada).